# C#: calling List<T>.Item[Int32] with an unpopulated list throws an exception sometimes, but not always

Tags: c#, list, exception, outofrangeexception

So, I've been using the following bit of code for a while, and it never threw an exception until recently.

```
// median-of-medians search:
const int MOM_GROUP_SIZE = 5;
List<KeyValuePair<int, float>> mediansList = indexPositionPairs;
while (mediansList.Count > 1) // could be only one because of outer loop, so check before first (inner) iteration!
{
    List<KeyValuePair<int, float>> groupMediansList;
    int fullGroupListLength = mediansList.Count / MOM_GROUP_SIZE;
    int remainderGroupSize = mediansList.Count % MOM_GROUP_SIZE;
    if (remainderGroupSize > 0)
    {
        groupMediansList = new List<KeyValuePair<int, float>>(fullGroupListLength + 1);
        // find last group median
        int startingIndex = fullGroupListLength * MOM_GROUP_SIZE;
        mediansList.Sort(startingIndex, remainderGroupSize, comp);
        groupMediansList[fullGroupListLength] = mediansList[startingIndex + remainderGroupSize / 2];
    }
    else
    {
        groupMediansList = new List<KeyValuePair<int, float>>(fullGroupListLength);
    }

    // groups of 5:
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < fullGroupListLength; ++i, j += MOM_GROUP_SIZE)
    {
        mediansList.Sort(j, MOM_GROUP_SIZE, comp);
        groupMediansList[i] = mediansList[j + MOM_MEDIAN_OFFSET];
    }

    // repeat on the group medians until only one remains
    mediansList = groupMediansList;
}
```

Now I'm getting an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` from the following line:

```
groupMediansList[fullGroupListLength] = mediansList[startingIndex + remainderGroupSize / 2];
```

Specifically, the left-hand side, where I'm attempting to set a value at an index. I'm getting the exception message:

> "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.\r\nParameter name: index"

Reading some of [Microsoft's online documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.item?view=netframework-4.7.2), it appears that it is indeed supposed to throw an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` when `index` is greater than or equal to `Count`.

However, as you can see further on in the code I use the same method to populate the list, and that never caused an exception. I'm also very skeptical that this particular block of code was never called before, as it would have required all the data sets this code was used on previously to have had sizes that were natural powers of 5.

This is the largest data set I've used this code on by far (1366921 elements!), so could that have had any effect? (Ideally it shouldn't, but you never know...)

For now, I'll just re-write this using arrays, but I'd like to understand what's going on here. I've always just assumed that addressing by index on a list would automatically extend the list if it went beyond the current size, and I'm worried what the implications are for my older projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, the `List<T>` constructor that takes an `int` parameter intializes a list with the specified *capacity*, not *length*. Which means the resulting list will always have an initial `Count` of zero.

Secondly, lists don't magically grow when you access their elements by index, only when you call `Add` or `Insert` (or`AddRange` or `InsertRange`, you get the gist). And even when they do grow, you're still not allowed to access any of the indices between `Count` and `Capacity`.

I'm skeptical that the second method "never caused an exception", since it's the same issue: you're creating an empty list with a specific capacity and then immediately try to access indices beyond its count. C# isn't like C++, where this could be chalked up to undefined behavior: here, it will throw, *every time*.

Since your algorithm appears to be "create a list of a predetermined length then replace individual elements", arrays are probably a better fit.

Answer (score 1):

```
groupMediansList = new List<KeyValuePair<int, float>>(fullGroupListLength + 1);
```

It looks like you're working under the assumption that setting the capacity of the list to `fullGroupListLength + 1` allows you to access indices 0 through `fullGroupListLength`. However, Capacity and Count are 2 different things. You can't access an index greater than or equal to `groupMediansList.Count`. The solution would be to add the required number of values to the list or maybe use a different collection, like an array.

Comment: The thing is, I _have been_ accessing indexes equal to or greater than Count, and it has never thrown an exception before. This exact code, which has run just fine on other datasets, invariably accesses an index equal to count many times in order to populate the list. What I _really_ want to know why it's being inconsistent.

Comment: @TravisReed I'd love to see a [mcve] that exemplifies your assertion that you can sometimes access an index greater than or equal to Count.

Comment: Hm... It doesn't seem to be working. Now I'm starting to doubt my own sanity.